# ASP DOt NET itemTemplate in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

How to add Textbox in gridview and how to access to it and perform some calculations like
Serno,Name,ServAmnt,Qty,Disc,netamt

```
netamt=servamnt*qty*discount
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Working with TemplateFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx) MSDN tutorial as a strating point:

Specify TemplateField.ItemTemplate;

Put the asp:TextBox control into template;

Bind the required TextBox’s property via the binding expression with the required field from the underlying datasource:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UnitPrice")%>'>
        </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I had added text boxes in the gridview,now want to show data in the textbox how can it be possible,please help me.!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am using this text field ---Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ServiceCode") %>' runat="server" Width="55px">  it is giving error  ---DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ServiceCode'. I changed this with Eval and Bind also it is giving the same error

Comment: it is necessary to use the “Eval” method as follows: Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, “ServiceCode") %>'

Comment: How to write textchanged event in item template in a gridview

Comment: How to display data in textbox that are created by an item template in a gridview the values are Serno,Name,ServAmnt,Qty,Disc,netamt,after display the data it should perform calculation like: netamt=(servamnt*qty)*discount help me to solve this problem..!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: calculation should be client-side or server-side?

Comment: Client side calculation,send me the code for gridview calculation

Comment: i have no idea how to do calculation,either to use javascript or through programming suggest me the steps......!!!!!!!!!